# Visual Studio Debug Issues with the "Step-into" command

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

So ive done developing on Visual Studio before, and normally I can step into my program the whole way through and see what it is doing in the more localized area. i.e. it will only step through the main function. I took a break from coding for about a month and I guess they updated something.

Basically, every time i step into just about any line, it will go through the xstring or xmemory file forever before returning to the program i wrote for 1 line, then doing the exact same thing again. Looking for a fix to this so i can get it back to how it was before. Thanks!

Comment: Check `Tools->Options->Debugging->General->Just my code`. I'm not exactly sure how good this option works for C++, though, as I rarely debug C++ code.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!